# Как добавить "готовый" элемент в массив?

Tags: java, массивы

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int z = scanner.nextInt();
double number = z / 2;
double number1 = 2 * z;
double number2 = z / 3;
int[] result = new int[3];
```

Как можно результаты `number`, `number1`, `number2` поместить в массив `result`?

Comment: во-первых, double number =z/2; здесь вы не получите double. это будет результат целочисленного деления, ведь с правой стороны только int. если нужен double , то можно так: double number =z/2d; аналогично для остальных строк. во-вторых, в массив int нельзя добавить double. сделайте так: double [] result = new double [3]; result [0] =z/2d; result [1] =2d*z; result [2] =z/3d;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
    result[0] = (int) number;
    result[1] = (int) number1;
    result[2] = (int) number2;
```